# How to add Data Points to be dynamic chart in canvasJS without knowing how many datas we need?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, canvas, canvasjs

I want to make array that in some way will hold all the objects without hard coding how many objects I got, that I want to get their data, ill make it clear with the code: `

```
    const localSavedCoins = getParsedToggledCurrencies(); // Brings JSON.parse array from localstorage which stores the name of the symbols.
    const firstData = []; // dataPoints
    const secondData = []; // dataPoints
    const thirdData = []; // dataPoints
    const fourthData = []; // dataPoints
    const fivthData = []; // dataPoints
    let addTextIfMissingDetails = [];


    const updateInterval = 2000;
    const dataLength = 20; // number of dataPoints visible at any point
    let addedSubtitles = false;
    localSavedCoins.forEach(coin => {
        const updateChart = function () {
            const date = new Date();
            let currentYear = date.getFullYear();
            let currentMonth = date.getMonth();
            let currentDay = date.getDate();
            let currentHour = date.getHours();
            let currentMinutes = date.getMinutes();
            let currentSeconds = date.getSeconds();

            $.ajax({
                url: `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${coin}&tsyms=USD`,
                success: information => {

                    const chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("contentDiv", {
                        exportEnabled: true,

                        zoomEnabled: true,
                        zoomType: "xy",
                        toolTip: {
                            shared: true,
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: "Coin Price Graph In USD"
                        },

                        subtitles: addTextIfMissingDetails
                        ,
                        axisX: {

                            valueFormatString: "HH:mm:ss",
                            title: "Time"
                        },
                        axisY: {

                            includeZero: false,
                            title: "Price in USD",
                            titleFontColor: "#4F81BC",
                            lineColor: "#4F81BC",
                            labelFontColor: "#4F81BC",
                            tickColor: "#4F81BC"

                        },
                        data: [
                            {

                                type: "spline",

                                name: localSavedCoins[0],
                                showInLegend: true,
                                dataPoints: firstData
                            },
                            {
                                type: "spline",
                                name: localSavedCoins[1],
                                showInLegend: true,
                                dataPoints: secondData
                            },
                            {
                                type: "spline",
                                name: localSavedCoins[2],
                                showInLegend: true,
                                dataPoints: thirdData
                            },
                            {
                                type: "spline",
                                name: localSavedCoins[3],
                                showInLegend: true,
                                dataPoints: fourthData
                            },
                            {
                                type: "spline",
                                name: localSavedCoins[4],
                                showInLegend: true,
                                dataPoints: fivthData
                            },

                        ]
                    })
                    if (information[Object.keys(information)[0]].USD === undefined && !addedSubtitles) {
                        addTextIfMissingDetails.push({
                            text: "Note: There are coins that are missing information"
                        })
                        addedSubtitles = true;
                    }
                    if (coin === localSavedCoins[0]) {
                        firstData.push({
                            x: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, currentHour, currentMinutes, currentSeconds),
                            y: information[Object.keys(information)[0]].USD
                        });
                    }
                    if (coin === localSavedCoins[1]) {
                        secondData.push({
                            x: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, currentHour, currentMinutes, currentSeconds),
                            y: information[Object.keys(information)[0]].USD
                        });
                    }
                    if (coin === localSavedCoins[2]) {
                        thirdData.push({
                            x: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, currentHour, currentMinutes, currentSeconds),
                            y: information[Object.keys(information)[0]].USD
                        });
                    }
                    if (coin === localSavedCoins[3]) {
                        fourthData.push({
                            x: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, currentHour, currentMinutes, currentSeconds),
                            y: information[Object.keys(information)[0]].USD
                        });
                    }
                    if (coin === localSavedCoins[4]) {
                        fivthData.push({
                            x: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, currentHour, currentMinutes, currentSeconds),
                            y: information[Object.keys(information)[0]].USD
                        });
                    }

                    chart.render();


                },
                error: () => {
                    alert("Error getting graph.");
                }
            })
        }
        updateChart(dataLength);

        const intervalAjaxCalls = setInterval(function () { updateChart() }, updateInterval);`
```

Here I hard coded how many objects I got (5) but what if I want to make it that the client will save 100 objects and show them on a chart, it's not realistic to hardcode 100 objects like that,I couldn't find any other way to store in 1 single data array all the objects so it will be without code copying.

Thanks in advance, ill provide more details, explanation as needed.

Comment: Where do you get the dataPoints from: is it a user input or do you get it from an API?
Can you give an example of the value of a dataPoint array?

Comment: @TOH19 I get it from the API at the success function,

Comment: Can you provide the HTML associated with your script? I want to try something please.

Comment: @TOH19  <div class="row" id="contentDiv"></div>)